# NullPointerException while Printing StringArray[] in Toast message in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, nullpointerexception

I'm working with some multiple StringArrary where I can print Toast message inside the respective StringArray but unfortunately, I'm facing a problem with showing toast outside the block. I'm sharing my code below

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    if (parent.getId() == R.id.region) {
        positions = spinner_region.getSelectedItemPosition();
        region_code = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.region_code);
        //Toast.makeText(this, region_code[positions], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (parent.getId() == R.id.district) {
        positions = spinner_district.getSelectedItemPosition();
        district_code = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.district_code);
        //Toast.makeText(this, district_code[positions], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (parent.getId() == R.id.upz) {
        positions = spinner_upz.getSelectedItemPosition();
        upz_code = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.upz_code);
        //Toast.makeText(this, upz_code[positions], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (parent.getId() == R.id.union) {
        positions = spinner_union.getSelectedItemPosition();
        union_code = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.upz_code);
        //Toast.makeText(this, union_code[positions], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (parent.getId() == R.id.village) {
        positions = spinner_village.getSelectedItemPosition();
        vill_code = this.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.village_code);
        //Toast.makeText(this, vill_code[positions], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    // Showing toast message here gives the error
    //but in individual codeblock this show perfectly
    Toast.makeText(this, union_code[positions]+upz_code[positions], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
}
```

My Variable is like

```
String[] upz_code;
String[] union_code;
```

My arrays are like

```
private String[] Union = {"A", "B",};
private String[] Union = {"C", "D",};
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array
```

This error caused the app to crash and don't understand the flaws. How can I overcome this or what I did wrong?

Comment: Please post the complete code block. Its possible you're trying to access a variable that is out of scope when you try to use it in the `Toast`

Comment: Please show more code, perhaps the entire function where this logic happens. It's not clear from the snippet you have shown - it seems to not start from the beginning of the function.

Comment: Hello, I update the code (full function). and hope you can now understand now.

Comment: Not yet @ArvindKumarAvinash

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if(union_code!=null){
    Toast.makeText(this,union_code[positions].toString() +upz_code[position].toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `if (union_code!=null)` if you want show toast in only null case. Or if you want to show Toast in every case you can use this one:-

```
Toast.makeText(this, 
    "" + union_code[positions].toString() + upz_code[position].toString(),
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I think, it should work.